# Linux no boot after cloning partitions

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, ssd, grub

I had and old HP Compaq laptop I wanted to upgrade because the IDE HDD was dying inside. Previously I had set up a Windows XP / Lubuntu 14 dual boot on it. After cloning the drive with Rescuezilla to an mSata SSD with and IDE adapter, and resizing the partitions, I can no longer boot into Lubuntu.

Windows XP boots up fine (after complaining and running checkdisk on the first attempt), but I can't get past Grub for Lubuntu. It complains about `attempt to read or write outside of disk 'hd0'` and the kernel not being loaded. Grub is **not** in rescue mode.

I did not just clone the partitions, because I wanted to use the full size of the new SSD (except for some reserve space), and the partitions for Linux were only a couple gigabytes.

Grub ls output: `(hd0) (hd0,msdos5) (hd0,msdos1)`

My partitions are as follows (MBR):

- Main Partition / MSDOS1 - Windows XP
- Extended Partition

  - Linux Main Partition / MSDOS5
  - Swap Partition

Here's what I tried so far:

- Checking for partition errors with GParted
- Manual boot from Grub with `set root=(hd0,msdos5)` and `linux *** root=/dev/sda5`, throws the same error like regular attempt.
- Reinstalling Grub from Rescuezilla with:
  `sudo mount /dev/sda5 /mnt`
  `sudo grub-install --boot-directory=/mnt/boot /dev/sda`
- Reinstalling Linux from live USB, SSD is not detected (complains about `failed to set xfermode (err_mask=0x40)` and `ata1: SRST failed`)

Notes:

- I had a hard time trying to nudge my partitions so they would be aligned on the SSD, I've heard that they can reduce the life of the device, especially on older OS-es without SSD support (since I'm running an Win XP as a first boot)
- Windows XP and Rescuezilla 2 works fine, but I could not detect the HDD with any other OS from Live USB. Even Rescuezilla 1 does not work.
- Memtest and HDD tests ran fine
- System: HP Compaq nx6110, 1.73 GHZ Pentium M, 1.5 GB DDR memory, 60 GB IDE (44 Pin) Fujitsu HDD (Now replaced), 256 GB Kingston mSata SSD w/ mSata to IDE 44 pin adapter

*Edit:
I tried boot-repair-iso and had the same issues.
I uploaded the logs to PasteBin and here:

- systemctl: https://pastebin.com/tAy14guQ
- journalctl: https://pastebin.com/8MvPumLe
- Boot Repair Log:

```
boot-repair-4ppa2075                                              [20240129_1152]

============================== Boot Info Summary ===============================

 => Grub2 (v2.00) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda and looks at sector 1 of 
    the same hard drive for core.img. core.img is at this location and looks 
    for (,2)/grub. It also embeds following components:
    
    modules
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    offsetio extcmd macho elf file gettext boot bufio verifiers crypto 
    terminal normal datetime date mmap drivemap blocklist archelp newc 
    vga_text relocator video chain ntldr search_label search_fs_file 
    search_fs_uuid search keylayouts at_keyboard pci usb usb_keyboard gcry_md5 
    hashsum gcry_crc gzio xzio lzopio lspci fshelp ext2 xfs acpi reboot 
    iso9660 gcry_sha1 div udf exfat font diskfilter raid6rec zstd btrfs ventoy 
    read halt video_fb vbe linux linux16 test true sleep echo bitmap gfxterm 
    bitmap_scale trig video_colors gfxmenu videotest videoinfo functional_test 
    videotest_checksum video_cirrus video_bochs vga minicmd help configfile tr 
    biosdisk disk ls tar zfs squash4 pbkdf2 gcry_sha512 password_pbkdf2 
    all_video png jpeg part_gpt part_msdos fat ntfs loopback 
    gfxterm_background procfs gfxterm_menu smbios
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       exfat
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Mounting failed:   fuse: mount failed: Device or resource busy

sda2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       iso9660
    Boot sector type:  Unknown
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg


================================ 0 OS detected =================================


================================ Host/Hardware =================================

CPU architecture: 32-bit
Video: Mobile 915GM/GMS/910GML Express Graphics Controller Mobile 915GM/GMS/910GML Express Graphics Controller from Intel Corporation Intel Corporation
Live-session OS is Ubuntu 32-bit (Boot-Repair-Disk 32bit 20211212, bionic, i686)

===================================== UEFI =====================================

BIOS/UEFI firmware: 68DTD Ver. F.13 from Hewlett-Packard
This live-session is in Legacy/BIOS/CSM mode (not in EFI mode).



============================= Drive/Partition Info =============================

Disks info: ____________________________________________________________________


Partitions info (1/3): _________________________________________________________


Partitions info (2/3): _________________________________________________________


Partitions info (3/3): _________________________________________________________


fdisk -l (filtered): ___________________________________________________________

Disk sda: 57.3 GiB, 61505273856 bytes, 120127488 sectors
Disk identifier: 0x8a46cb63
     Boot     Start       End   Sectors  Size Id Type
sda1  *         2048 120061951 120059904 57.3G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
sda2       120061952 120127487     65536   32M ef EFI (FAT-12/16/32)
Disk dm-0: 930 MiB, 975175680 bytes, 1904640 sectors
Disk identifier: 0x25aca9fd
      Boot Start     End Sectors  Size Id Type
dm-0p1 *        0 1904639 1904640  930M 17 Hidden HPFS/NTFS
Disk zram0: 746 MiB, 782217216 bytes, 190971 sectors

parted -lm (filtered): _________________________________________________________

sda:61.5GB:scsi:512:512:msdos: USB  SanDisk 3.2Gen1:;
1:1049kB:61.5GB:61.5GB:::boot;
2:61.5GB:61.5GB:33.6MB:fat16::esp;

blkid (filtered): ______________________________________________________________

NAME   FSTYPE   UUID                                 PARTUUID                             LABEL                  PARTLABEL
sda                                                                                                              
├─sda1 exfat    4E21-0000                            8a46cb63-01                          Ventoy                 
└─sda2 iso9660  2021-12-15-23-51-16-00                                                    Boot-Repair-Disk 32bit 

Mount points (filtered): _______________________________________________________

                    Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/ventoy      0 100% /cdrom
/dev/sda2               0 100% /media/lubuntu/Boot-Repair-Disk 32bit

Mount options (filtered): ______________________________________________________

/dev/mapper/ventoy iso9660         ro,noatime,nojoliet,check=s,map=n,blocksize=2048
/dev/sda2          iso9660         ro,nosuid,nodev,relatime,nojoliet,check=s,map=n,blocksize=2048

====================== sda2/boot/grub/grub.cfg (filtered) ======================


==================== sda2: Location of files loaded by Grub ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
            ?? = ??             boot/grub/grub.cfg                             1

======================== Unknown MBRs/Boot Sectors/etc =========================

Unknown BootLoader on sda2




Suggested repair: ______________________________________________________________

The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility would not act on the boot.
```

*Edit 2: I got booted up Rescuezilla 2, here are some interesing diffs I found in boot:

- Old:

```
jan 29 11:51:28 lubuntu kernel: ata1.00: qc timeout (cmd 0x47)
jan 29 11:51:28 lubuntu kernel: ata1.00: READ LOG DMA EXT failed, trying PIO
jan 29 11:51:28 lubuntu kernel: ata1.00: ATA Identify Device Log not supported
jan 29 11:51:28 lubuntu kernel: ata1.00: Security Log not supported
jan 29 11:51:28 lubuntu kernel: ata1.01: ATAPI: MATSHITAUJ-840D, 1.02, max MWDMA2
jan 29 11:51:28 lubuntu kernel: ata1.00: failed to set xfermode (err_mask=0x40)
jan 29 11:51:28 lubuntu kernel: ata1: link is slow to respond, please be patient (ready=0)
jan 29 11:51:28 lubuntu kernel: ata1: SRST failed (errno=-16)
jan 29 11:51:28 lubuntu kernel: ata1: link is slow to respond, please be patient (ready=0)
jan 29 11:51:28 lubuntu kernel: ata1: SRST failed (errno=-16)
jan 29 11:51:28 lubuntu kernel: ata1: link is slow to respond, please be patient (ready=0)
jan 29 11:51:28 lubuntu kernel: ata1: SRST failed (errno=-16)
jan 29 11:51:28 lubuntu kernel: ata1: SRST failed (errno=-16)
jan 29 11:51:28 lubuntu kernel: ata1: reset failed, giving up
jan 29 11:51:28 lubuntu kernel: ata1.00: disabled
jan 29 11:51:28 lubuntu kernel: ata1.01: disabled
```

- On Rescuezilla:

```
jan 29 12:07:01 ubuntu kernel: ata1: lost interrupt (Status 0x58)
jan 29 12:07:01 ubuntu kernel: ata1: drained 65536 bytes to clear DRQ
jan 29 12:07:01 ubuntu kernel: ata1.00: supports DRM functions and may not be fully accessible
jan 29 12:07:01 ubuntu kernel: ata1.00: supports DRM functions and may not be fully accessible
jan 29 12:07:01 ubuntu kernel: ata1.00: device reported invalid CHS sector 0
jan 29 12:07:01 ubuntu kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
jan 29 12:07:01 ubuntu kernel: sda: detected capacity change from 0 to 256060514304
```

Comment: I've just found about Boot-Repair [link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair), II will put it on a USB stick, and see if it can figure out something.

Comment: If this doesn't work, use another cloning software. Resize partitions only after the new disk is proven to be working.

Comment: I tried the drive with sata and had no issues... Maybe a compatibility issue?
Here similar behavior is reported as Rescuezilla boot log:
[https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=247820](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=247820)

Comment: I've run boot-repair from rescuezilla. It managed to find stuff, and repair it, but it did not work, same errors in grub, this time in rescue mode. However, it.warn me about an old bios potentially having errors with bootable partitions not being in the ~100gb limit. (Win XP partition is 128gb) I will make some space and try again)

Answer (score -1):

I think I mostly managed to fix my issue. I did the following:

- Boot Rescuezille 2 from a live USB
- Moved my partitions around so there would be 1 GB of space before the main Windows partition
- created an empty ext4 partition there and made set the bootable flag on it
- installed boot-repair and ran it; selecting the advanced options

  - in the advanced options I specified the newly created partition, so Grub would be installed there
  - and checked the fix for old bioses option
- and I ran it

Now I managed to boot into Lubuntu on the SSD!